# Vista Passwordless Printer Sharing

Tags: windows-vista, home-networking

Is it possible to share files over lan with password protection turned on for file sharing but at the same time have the printer not prompt for password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Once you enable password protection, all filesharing / printer connections **must** be authenticated with a valid system username and a password. The closest you could achieve would be to create a guest account and set a password on it (i.e., `guest`), and then let people use that if they do not have another account on the Vista computer.

Comment: Thanks, looks like serving fiiles a file server might be more suitable.